# Point main domain to a directory other then root using httpd.conf

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp, httpd.conf

I need to point my domain from the root directory to a folder within the root directory using the httpd.conf on my server. Lets just use www.mysite.com as a example domain and mysite as the folder within the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You means that now your website is running as www.mysite.com/mysite and you want the content of mysite only as www.mysite.com, have you tried moving data from mysite to your document root directory. Might be it will work for you